# Let $f\in L[0,a]$, $g(x) = \int_x^a\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$ show $\int_0^agdx = \int_0^afdx$

Tags: real-analysis

This is what I am trying to do:

Let $ 1_{[y,1]}(x)=\begin{cases}1,&\ x\leq t\leq a\\ 0,&\ otherwise\end{cases} $

$\int_0^agdx = \int_0^a(\int_x^a\frac{f(t)}{t}dt)dx= \int_0^a(\int_0^a\frac{f(t)}{t}1_{[x,a]}dt)dx = \int_0^adx\int_0^a\frac{f(t)}{t}1_{[x,a]}dt$...

Do I on the right direction?

Comment: What is $L[0,a]$?

Comment: @Momo That's Lebesgue integrable in [0,a]. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Lebesgue integrable. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it seems related, so I tried to do this problem in the similar way. But still stuck

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_0^a g(x)\, dx = \int_0^a \int_x^a \frac{f(t)}{t}dt\, dx = \int_0^a \int_0^t \frac{f(t)}{t} dx\, dt = \int_{0}^a f(t) dt $$ since $0 < x < t <a$.

Comment: How do you get $\int_0^a\int_0^t\frac{f(t)}{t}dxdt$?

Comment: Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: For this proof to be correct, you have to prove the assumptions for some version of Fubini theorem hold. Only then you can say that the iterated integrals are equal.

Comment: No, I don't think it's correct. How do you use it?

Comment: @Momo, of course. But I don't think I need to give the complete details especially if this is a homework.

Comment: That said, I think, @Kyle, you should work on it.

Comment: @Isko10986 OK. I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: If one is worried about integrability issue, prove this when $f$ is non-negative (so that we can use Tonelli's theorem instead). Then the general case follows by writing $f = f_+ - f_-$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you!